# Teaching an abstract algebra class involving modules, best way to introduce operations on modules?

Tags: modules

I am about to teach a few classes on modules and their operations, namely the following: direct product, direct sum, and finitely generated modules. The following is the "skeleton" version of how I plan to talk about them.

1. The direct sum of modules $M_1, M_2$ is defined to be$$M_1 \oplus M_2 = \{(m_1, m_2) : m_1 \in M_1, m_2 \in M_2\}.$$The action of $A$ is given by $a(m_1, M_2) : = (am_1, am_2)$. More generally, for any set $I$ and any collection of $A$-modules $\{M_i\}_{i \in I}$, one has a **direct product** $A$-module$$\prod_{i \in I} M_i = \{(m_i \in M_i)_{i \in I}\}.$$We will often write an element of $\prod_{i \in I} M_i$ in the form $\sum_{i \in I} m_i$ instead of $(m_i \in M_i)_{i \in I}$.
2. The $A$-module $\prod_{i \in I} M_i$ contains a submodule$$\bigoplus_{i \in I} M_i = \{(m_i \in M_i)_{i \in I} : m_i = 0 \text{ for all but finitely many }i\},$$called **direct sum**. In particular, for any $n \ge 1$, we write$$M^n := \underbrace{M \oplus \dots \oplus M}_{n \text{ times}}.$$
3. The sum of a collection of submodules $M_i \subseteq M$, $i \in I$, is defined to be$$\sum_{i \in I} M_i = \{m_{i_1} + \dots + m_{i_j} : m_{i_j} \in M_{i_j}\}.$$
4. The submodule generated by a fixed element $m \in M$ is defined to be$$Am = \{am : a \in A\}.$$More generally, for any collection $\{m_i\}_{i \in I} \subset M$, of elements of $M$, one has$$\sum_{i \in I} Am_i \subset M,$$the submodule generated by the $m_i$. We say that $M$ is **finitely generated** if there exist $m_1, \dots, m_k \in M$ such that $M = Am_1 + \dots + Am_k$.

What are some good things to add about these things which other people have found helpful when teaching/learning about these things?

Best,
C

Comment: I am not going to say that this question is necessarily off-topic, but http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/ strikes me as a better place to ask your question.

Comment: you might contemplate answers to the question: "why would anyone want to know any of these definitions?"

Comment: A more modern treatment is that the direct sum and direct product of $\{M_i\}_{i\in I}$ is a module $M$ with maps either from or to the $M_i$ that is largest or smallest, in the sense that if there is any other module $N$ with such maps, then there is a unique map to or from $M$ commuting with the given maps. From this, one can show that your definitions prove that direct sums and products exist in the category of modules, and they are unique (up to unique isomorphism) by functoriality. Also, the product you define should be the set of maps $m:I\to M$ such that $m_i\in M_i$.

Comment: @roysmith The functorial definition provides at least a partial answer. Given a bunch of $M_i$, it is natural to want to look at a module that naturally "contains" all of the $M_i$ and is as small as possible (that's the direct sum) and a module that naturally maps to all of the $M_i$ and is as small as possible (that's the direct product). Of course, one can also motivate from the students knowledge that if $K$ is a field, then $K^n$ is very interesting, and it's not unnatural to ask what happens if we allow $n$ to "be infinite".

Comment: Asked at [Mathematics Educators](http://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/9659/77) as requested.

Comment: the structure theorem for finitely generated abelian groups, and modules over a pid, motivates wanting to know about at least finite direct products as well as quotients.